# Changing bullet to dash ( -) in Google Document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

We have a function to set a glyphType to `DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET`.

```
listItem.setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET)
```

However, is there any way to set the glyphType to dash (-)?

For example, our list is below.

```
- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/list-item#setGlyphType(GlyphType)

Answer (score 1):

**Linux solution**

If you've got text you want to be a hyphenated list, and haven't already got a bulleted list, this should work for you.

I found that there is no hyphen glyph type in google script, so a direct swap of the (horrible) default bullet glyph is not possible.

None of the above solutions worked for me in google script, or any of the many variants I implemented.

Then I thought ... what about doing this using `xdotool`.
Xdotool hits keyboard keys for you programatically.

If you have linux you have bash and xdotool which you can script to do all the hard work, creating a hyphenated list for n number of document rows.

Then simply connect the script to various keyboard shortcuts, one shortcut for each specific number of rows.

So for example when on my laptop I press
fn+ctrl   + h  + n, where n is a number, between 1 and 9, this allows me to hyphenate for up to 9 rows. I then just repeat as necessary, if there are more rows.

Here is the simple code to achieve this, which works on my T440s thinkpad running the latest version of linux and Openbox window manager.

```
#!/bin/bash

# make sure you pass an argument between 1 and 9 to the script
count=$1

# use `xev` to identify the equivalent keys on your system.
#    likley they are the same

xdotool key Home      # key Home

for i in $(seq 1 $count); do

  xdotool key space;  # key a space
  sleep 0.10;
  xdotool key minus;  # key a hyphen
  sleep 0.10;
  xdotool key space;  # key a space
  sleep 0.10;
  xdotool key Down;   # key arrow down
  sleep 0.10;
  xdotool key Home;   # key Home 
  sleep 0.10;

done
```

I then use the Openbox keyboard short cut as described above within the Openbox set-up file `rc.xml`.
Here are two of the five shortcuts. It's easy to see what the rest might be, up to 9,

```
<keybind key="c-XF86WakeUp">
    
#C-fn
#C-fn

# c-fn-h #############################################################
##########                                                  ########## 
##########      Google docs hyphenated list                 ##########
##########                                                  ########## 
######################################################################


#C-fn-h google docs hyphenated list

#C-fn-h
#C-fn-h


   <keybind key="h">

        #  create a 1 hyphen list
        <keybind key="1"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
    /home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 1
    '</command></action></keybind>

        #  create a 2 hyphen list
        <keybind key="2"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
    /home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 2
    '</command></action></keybind>


#  create a 3 hyphen list
<keybind key="3"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 3
'</command></action></keybind>

#  create a 4 hyphen list
<keybind key="4"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 4
'</command></action></keybind>

#  create a 5 hyphen list
<keybind key="5"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 5
'</command></action></keybind>

#  create a 6 hyphen list
<keybind key="6"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 6
'</command></action></keybind>

#  create a 7 hyphen list
<keybind key="7"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 7
'</command></action></keybind>

#  create a 8 hyphen list
<keybind key="8"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 8
'</command></action></keybind>

#  create a 9 hyphen list
<keybind key="9"><action name="Execute"><command>bash -c '
/home/$USER/scripts/script_google_docs_hyphenated_list/google_docs_hyphenated_list.sh 9
'</command></action></keybind>
    
   </keybind>

</keybind>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dash is not [listed](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/glyph-type) as a glyph type. But here is a work around. You could make you own pre-filled list with place holder items in a master document, copy the list and replace the items into the target document. Perhaps this is a lot of effort for styling bullets, but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes [@Jason Allshorn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5086349/jason-allshorn) is correct. I was able to set a custom bullet using apps script. I have a template doc that I copy to make a new doc. In this template I created a list item, text "list item", with my custom bullet glyph. Google, what is up with those giant dots? Ugly! I find that list item in the doc, copy it, and remove it. Code below:

```
function getListItem(ss, doc) {
    var body = doc.getBody();
    for (var i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
        var child = body.getChild(i);
        var childType = child.getType();
        if (childType == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM && child.getText() == 'list item') {
            var customBulletListItem = child.copy();
            body.removeChild(child);
            break;
        }
    }
    return customBulletListItem;
}
```

... then when I add a list item (li), I do the following:

```
body.insertListItem(i, li.copy());
body.getChild(i).replaceText("list item", "My new list item text");
body.getChild(i).setIndentFirstLine(0).setIndentStart(15);
body.getChild(i).editAsText().setBold(true);
```

This gets me my custom bullet glyph. The last two lines fix the huge indent on list items and bold the line. Google, what is up with the huge indents? Ugly!